# Passing function arguments to $scope.$apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I'm using $scope.$apply for callbacks, specifically with Stripe. Currently I have some code like

```
var stripeCallback = function (status, response) {
    if (!response.error) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
};

$scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.errorMessage = 'Processing...';
    $scope.buttonDisabled = true;
    // can't use bindings for some reason
    var myForm = $('#paymentform');
    Stripe.createToken(myForm, function (status, response) {
        $scope.$apply(stripeCallback);
    });
};
```

The problem with this is that I can't get any arguments to `stripeCallback`, namely `response`. Is there any way I can pass function arguments to `$scope.$apply`? I haven't been able to find any reference to this is the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap `stripeCallback` into an anonymous function:

```
var stripeCallback = function (status, response) {
    ....
};

$scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.errorMessage = 'Processing...';
    $scope.buttonDisabled = true;
    // can't use bindings for some reason
    var myForm = $('#paymentform');
    Stripe.createToken(myForm, function (status, response) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            stripeCallback(status, response);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: This question smelled like either an absolute JavaScript beginner or some code-blockade in OPs brain. ;-)

Comment: No problem. The question was perfectly clearly asked so you deserve an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just call `$scope.$apply()` after calling your callback:

```
Stripe.createToken(myForm, function (status, response) {
    stripeCallback(status, response);
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: Neat! That's good to know. I just read about `$digest` and this makes more sense now.

Comment: is it considered better practice to use `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()` in cases like this?

Comment: @sean9999, as [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) explain, you should normally use `$apply()`, otherwise you risk not having all of your views updated.  If you are absolutely positive that only `$scope`'s view needs to be updated, you can use `$digest` to be more efficient.  But what if things change in the future?  Use `$apply` and be safe rather than sorry.